# Did I correctly translate this pseudocode into Java? I'm particularly looking at line 3 in the pseudocode for this sorting algorithm

Tags: java, sorting, pseudocode

Did I correctly translate this pseudocode into Java? I am particularly looking at line 3 in the pseudocode for this sorting algorithm.

Here is the pseudocode that I am attempting to translate:

```
    Sort-Array(A)
    for i = 1 to (A.length – 1)
        for j = (i + 1) to A.length
            if (A[j] > A[i])
                // swap A[i] and A[j]
                buffer = A[j]
                A[j] = A[i]
                A[i] = buffer
```

My translation:

```
static void bubbleSort(int array[]) {
  int size = array.length;
  
  // loop to access each array element
  for (int i = 1; i < size - 1; i++)
   
     // loop comparing the array elements
     for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
     
        // compare two adjacent elements
        // changing > to < to sort in either order
        if (array[j] > array[i]) {
        
           // swapping elements. 
           int buffer = array[j];
           array[j] = array[i];
           array[i] = buffer;
           
        }
```

Comment: For zero based arrays as in java: `for (int i = 0; i < array.length /*-1*/; i++)` and `for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++)`. Descending sort by the way. The convention in java is `static void bubbleSort(int[] array) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but there is one mistake. In the pseudocode you start with i = 1, because in pseudocode we dont start counting at 0. in your programm you have to start at 0, because the first element of an array start at array[0], not array[1].

Comment: Excellent- appreciate the assitance!

Answer (score 1):

Line #3 translated correctly but that's not actually a bubble sort algorithm. Here `if (array[j] > array[i])` you compare all the further elements with `i` element and in bubble sort you need to compare only neighbor elements of array. So, basically to transform it to bubble sort you need to compare `j` with `j-1`